# Only display selected fields to the view using Laravel Query Builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I have quotes I am displaying to the screen one at a time upon each page refresh. The data is displaying fine from the DB; the issue is that I am getting the (id) display on the screen as well when I only need the quote and author name. How do I "exclude" the id field from displaying in my view?

**Controller**

```php
public function index()
{
    $quotes = DB::table('quotes')->inRandomOrder()->first();

    return view('home', compact('quotes'));
}
```

**Blade/View**

```php
@foreach($quotes as $quote)
    <p>{{$quote}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: try `$quotes = DB::table('quotes')->select('quote', 'author')->inRandomOrder()->first();`. replacing 'quote' and 'author' by the fields names in your table

Comment: You should put your answer in a real answer so I can upvote and accept :D

Answer (score 4):

**Edit** based on the comment of @devk:

> Generally answers OPs question, but the code here (and in OPs post)
>   doesn't exactly make sense. The ->first() will return null or a single
>   quote, but the @foreach(..) is used like it's a collection of quotes

you can do the query like this:

```
$quote = DB::table('quotes')->select('quote', 'author')->inRandomOrder()->first();
```

replacing 'quote' and 'author' by the fields names in your table.
And return te quote:

```
return view('home', compact('quote'));
```

And in blade show the object:

```
<p>{{$quote}}</p>
```

or show the fields:

```
@isset($quote)
    // $quote is defined and is not null...
    <p>{{$quote->quote}}</p>
    <small>{{$quote->author}}</small>
@endisset
```

If you want to show multiple quotes, do the query like this:

```
$quotes = DB::table('quotes')->select('quote', 'author')->inRandomOrder()->get();
```

or

```
$quotes = DB::table('quotes')->select('quote', 'author')->inRandomOrder()->take(5)->get();
```

And in blade you can loop through the collection:

```
@foreach($quotes as $quote)
    <p>{{$quote}}</p>
@endforeach
```

or

```
@foreach($quotes as $quote)
    <p>{{$quote->quote}}</p>
    <small>{{$quote->author}}</small>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I can accept the answer in 6 mins! Thank you @porloscerros

Comment: Generally answers OPs question, but the code here (and in OPs post) doesn't exactly make sense. The `->first()` will return `null` or a single quote, but the `@foreach(..)` is used like it's a collection of quotes.

Comment: Oh! I had missed that. I edited my answer. Thank you @devk!